# Clustering example in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have an **increasing** input vector like this `{0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9}` and want to cluster the inputs like this `{{0, 1}, {3}, {5, 6, 7}, {9}}` i.e cluster only the integers that are neighbors. The data structure `std::vector<std::vector<int>> solution(const std::vector<int>& input)`

Comment: is the input array always increasing? if no, are the clusters always increasing? does decreasing count? (4, 3, 2)

Comment: Please provide a solution attempt in order to start working from some starting place

Comment: for(i=0, i <input.size(), i++){
    i < input.size()-1
}
vector<int>temp;
//creating temp vector for each cluster
while (input[i+1]-input[i] ==1){
    temp.push_back(input[i]);
    i++;
}

Comment: I think this should be the for loop and the while loop.. and yes the input array is always increasing.. no decreasing does not count

Comment: I think [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) will be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I usually advocate for not giving away solutions, but it looks like you're getting bogged down with indices and temporary vectors. Instead, standard iterators and algorithms make this task a breeze:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> solution(std::vector<int> const &input) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> clusters;

    // Special-casing to avoid returning {{}} in case of an empty input
    if(input.empty())
        return clusters;

    // Loop-and-a-half, no condition here
    for(auto it = begin(input);;) {
        // Find the last element of the current cluster
        auto const last = std::adjacent_find(
            it, end(input),
            [](int a, int b) { return b - a > 1; }
        );

        if(last == end(input)) {
            // We reached the end: register the last cluster and return
            clusters.emplace_back(it, last);
            return clusters;
        }

        // One past the end of the current cluster
        auto const gap = next(last);

        // Register the cluster
        clusters.emplace_back(it, gap);

        // One past the end of a cluster is the beginning of the next one
        it = gap;
    }
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59d23333a6924a61) <sup>(lame output formatting free of charge)</sup>